# Calling python module from python with arguments

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I have a situation where I have directory structure as below:

```
p
|
+--a
|  |
|  + file1.py
|
+--b
   |
   + file2.py
```

`file1.py` is something I cannot modify, though it has a `main()` which accepts command line arguments (it uses `argparse`).

I need to call `file1.main()` from `file2.py`, and I am able to call it. However I am not sure how I can pass the arguments without needing to go through `os` or the `subprocess` package, as it'd be preferable if I don't pass the data back to os and then back to `file2`. Is there an elegant way with which I can pass the arguments object directly from `file2`?

Comment: Is the `main` and `argparse` using in `file1` in the `__name__` block?  That is, does it run only when `file1` is called as a script, or does it also run when `file1` is imported?

Comment: no, it does not run on import, has to be explicitly called.